# Why is python responding to an Android client different depending on the use of a dictionary?

Tags: android, python, mysql-python

I have been writing an application for Android that receives a response from a cgi-script (python) that access data from a MySQL DB in order to generate dynamic content. I receive the response fine. I am trying to use a python dictionary server-side so that I can respond to the android client with a JSON array. During debugging, if I don't use a dictionary, like this:

```
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * from posts")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
if cur:
    print row[1] #this entry in the DB is a datetime field, however other fields suffer from the same problem
else:
    print "Something went wrong."
```

In that case, I get the response on the android client in a desirable format, such as 2013-06-06 23:03:47.

On the other hand, if I create a dictionary and place the value under a key such as my column name like this:

```
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * from posts")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
if cur:
    for row in rows:
        d = {'time':row[1]}
        print d
else:
    print "Something went wrong."
```

Then the response I receive has formatting issues. I receive a response like:

```
{'time':datetime.datetime(2013,6,6.23.3.47)}
```

The same happens with numbers that I've used Decimal on. Instead of showing as just the number, as they do in a normal print, inside the dictionary (response) they show as:

```
Decimal('12.345678')
```

Could anyone with more knowledge than me shed some light on the subject?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must convert the values to the correct format. When you save them to a database the database handles this conversion, and when you select the rows the items in the rows are *not* `datetime` or `Decimal` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print inside of a dictionary (or any container), it shows the `__repr__` ("code representation") of the object; whereas when you use `print` directionly, it prints the `__str__` (human-readable) representation of the object.

```
import decimal
mynum = decimal.Decimal('12')
print mynum # 12
print [mynum] # [Decimal('12')
```

You can see this by adding a `print repr` line to your code:

```
if cur:
    print repr(row[1]) # will be Decimal...
    print row[1] # looks like a number
```

You can use `Decimal` exactly like a regular float, except that it maintains complete precision, it makes little difference to any arithmetic you might do to it.

In terms of `repr` vs. `str`. The general idea is that `str` is easy to understand and view, whereas `repr` is code-oriented and often `eval(repr(obj)) == obj` would hold.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was able to get what I wanted by using `d = {'time':str(row[1])}`. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user2465724 yep, it's the same thing for both decimal and datetime and, if you were using it anywhere else (i.e., dumping it with json) it would fix itself that way too.